# Add extra labels to line charts

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart that has 100 points on X Axis, each 25 points need to be labels separately.
Its like there are 4 rectangles in the chart conceptually each covering 25 points. How can i put a label in this example on each rectangle.
I have not found anything in the API that seems to support this.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I understand what would you like to achieve. Do your 100 points are in the one series? Could provide some visualization of your concept?

Comment: Hi, i will try but high-chart supports Title, Sub Title to display text information on a given chart that we can control where it appears, Similarly would like to place 4 more such textual information (labels) at specific XY position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what would you like to achieve, you can use the `annotations module` or `Renderer API` to draw labels on the chart. I suppose you can also use the `xAxis.blotBands` in this case. Check the following docs for getting more information:

**Docs:**
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines

Here is an example code of rendered rectangle with text:

```
chart: {
        events: {
          render: function() {
    
            let chart = this,
              x1 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(0),
              x2 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(25),
              width = x2 - x1,
              height = chart.plotSizeY,
              y = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0) - height,
              text = 'My text';
    
            // RECTANGLE
            chart.renderer
              .rect(x1, y, width, height)
              .attr({
                stroke: 'red',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                zIndex: 3,
              })
              .add();
    
            // TEXT
            chart.renderer
              .text(text, x1 + width / 2, y)
              .attr({
                align: 'center',
                zIndex: 4,
              })
              .css({
                fontSize: '15px'
              })
              .add();
          }
        }
      },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3nqjwha5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising and i am exploring more. But how can i add My text three times lets say at 20:125 , 50:125 and 80:125 in your example?

Comment: Actually this is very clear and what i was looking -> https://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer , thanks for pointing to renderer

Comment: There is a problem with this approach though, this does not work well with download or print chart, not sure if there is another way to add the text/labels that would work with this.

Comment: Could you specify what does not work well or provide an example? Do you use your own export server or export module in this case?

Comment: I was referring to inbuilt print options (hamburger menu) in high-charts which are pretty cool  but when you use renderer to add extra text it gets jumbled up when you print in any format.